# Variance of continuous Random Variable negative?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am having trouble finding the Variance for this question.

> The proportion of salt X left in the salt shakers at the end of the day at a crowded restaurant has a probability density function given by
>
> f(x) { 2x for 0 < x < 1

```
   0 other wise
```

> There are 80 salt shakers in the restaurant with each one having a capacity of 3 ounces of salt and they are all filled and used independently of each other. Find the expectation and standard deviation of T = the total amount of salt needed to fill the 80 salt shakers at the end of the day?

Here is what I am getting -

E(X) = an integral 0 to 1 (2x^2) , which then equals 2/3.

I then take the opposite of the 2/3 being that is how much left in the salt shaker and get 1/3 which is how much is gone.
I then multiply 1/3(3) and see that one ounce needs to be refilled in each salt shaker.
Then I multiply 1(80) to account for the 80 salt shakers.
So my E(T) = 80

Now to find the Variance wouldn't I just find the integral from 0 to 1 of f(x)(x^2)? and then subtract E(t)^2 from that to fond the Variance?
When I do that I am getting a negative number and I know that it isn't right.
Any help?

Comment: Note that you are integrating with respect to $x$ but subtracting the squared expectation of $t$.  Different variables!

Comment: Crap, so if I leave the variance to 1.5 and subtract the expected number of ounces lost which is 1^2. I would get .5. Than would I multiply that .5 by 80 and then take the root?

Comment: To simplify your life a little, work through the mean and variance of how much salt is used.  The mean of how much is left is just 240-how much is used, and the variance of how much is left = the variance of how much is used.

Comment: I am getting 9.5 as my final answer. Is this correct?

Comment: When calculating the variance, you have two effects.  The first is that you have 80 salt shakers, so you will want to sum the variances of each of the shakers (i.e., multiply the variance of the shaker by 80.)  The second is that each shaker has 3 ounces of salt, but your original variable has a range of $(0,1)$.  You need to change the range to $(0,3)$ because you need to deal with ounces of salt, not percentages of the shaker; this will multiply the variance at the salt shaker level by 9 ($Var(aX) = a^2Var(X)$).

Comment: When you have found the right answer, you can answer your own question, so it is not left "hanging"

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a textbook problem rather than a restaurant management problem,
so I will give an outline leading to the answer. Your answer is a good start.
Now, I hope you will turn it into a coherent mathematical demonstration with reasons for each step: Use $E(a + bX)= a + bE(X),\,$ $Var(a + bX) = b^2Var(X),\,$ and for independent
random variables $X_1, X_2,$ you have $Var(X_1 + X_2) = Var(X_1)+Var(X_2).$

The random variable $X$ has $E(X) = 2/3,$ which you have already found.
You can also show that $Var(X) = 1/18.$

The salt *used* in the $i$th shaker is $Y_i = 3(1-X_i),$ so 
$$E(Y_i) = E(3 - 3X_i) = 3 - E(3X_i) = 3 - 2 = 1.$$

Now you need to find $Var(Y_i),$ based on $Var(X).$

Finally, $T = \sum_{i=1}^{80}Y_i.$ Use that to find $E(T)$ and $Var(T).$

Here is a simulation in R statistical software, based on the fact that
$X \sim \mathsf{Beta}(2,1).$ With a million iterations (days) one can
expect results for $E(T)$ and $SD(T)$ accurate to about three significant digits,
perhaps better.

```
set.seed(1018)
t = replicate(10^6, sum(3*(1-rbeta(80,2,1))))
mean(t);  sd(t);  var(t)
[1] 80.00621  # aprx E(T) = 80
[1] 6.325178
[1] 40.00787
mean(t > 90)
[1] 0.059156  # aprx P(T > 90)
```

Here is a histogram of the simulated distribution of $T$ (in Halloween orange).
Because of the Central Limit Theorem, the distribution of $T$ is very nearly normal (normal density curve shown in blue). Can you find a normal approximation
of $P(T > 90)?$

[image]

*Note:* Perhaps you'll want to look at Wikipedia's article on [beta distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question above was found by finding F(X^2) which = 1/2

1/2 - (2/3)^2 = .05

.05(80) = 4.44 (80 being the amount of salt shaker summed up.)

4.44(3)^2 = 40

root(40) = 6.3

Comment: Because it is difficult to connect these numbers with the correct answers, could you explain what you believe these numbers represent?

Comment: Why are you subtracting the square of $1/3$?  The mean of $x$ is $2/3$...